# object reference not set to an instance of an object ( keypresseventargs of array textbox)

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have an array textbox for boxpoamount,boxpounitprice and boxpoqty and i want to validate it that it will only accept a number but im getting an error in object reference not set to an instance of an object in this line

```
 If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And boxpoqty.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0) Or (e.KeyChar = "-" And boxpoqty.Text.Length = 0)) Then
```

Help please

This is the complete code

```
      Private Sub loadpokeypressvalidation(ByRef boxpoamount As TextBox, ByRef boxpounitprice As TextBox, ByRef boxpoqty As TextBox)

  Dim e As KeyPressEventArgs
            If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And boxpoqty.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0) Or (e.KeyChar = "-" And boxpoqty.Text.Length = 0)) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only")
                e.Handled = True
            End If
            If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And boxpoamount.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0) Or (e.KeyChar = "-" And boxpoamount.Text.Length = 0)) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only")
                e.Handled = True
            End If
            If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And boxpounitprice.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0) Or (e.KeyChar = "-" And boxpounitprice.Text.Length = 0)) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only")
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End Sub

     Private Sub loadvalidkeypress()
            Dim controlall As Integer = Val(txtpoitemno.Text)

            For i As Integer = 0 To controlall - 1
                loadpokeypressvalidation(newpounitpricebox(i), newpoamountbox(i), newpoqtybox(i))
            Next

        End Sub
```

Comment: You have multiple conditions in the line error.
Can you proceed to each condition one by one to check which one give you the error ?

Comment: If Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Or (e.KeyChar = "." And boxpoqty.Text.IndexOf(".") < 0) Or (e.KeyChar = "-" And boxpoqty.Text.Length = 0)) Then          this line

Comment: Is it really necessary to validate each keystroke?  Do you really need to scold the user with a MessageBox for a typo?  Validate whne the user clicks Ok/Update/Done, you will both be happier.  You should be using AndAlso and OrElse instead of And and Or

Comment: yes so that it will be known immediately rather than later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be issue with KeyPressEventArgs.

Why don't you try with Regex as below,

```
    If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(TextboxEmail.Text, "[^0-9]") = False Then
      ' not valid
      ' ...
    End If
```

Comment: You need to loop through your textboxes array. And within loop, you need to use this if condition to make sure there is only numbers within textbox.

Comment: yes i loop it already but the thing with this code is  it still accept letter.

Comment: Well, you can insert letters in textbox, but once you validate that textbox using regex, it will not validate your textbox and returns false. So in that case you need to display message where it says, invalid input.